# How bad is this? 3GB total bytes allocated in 30 seconds

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, allocation

In coding a physics-based game, I have created everything from subclassed NSObjects.  Force vectors are stored in NSArrays for each particle object, then acceleration, velocity, and position are calculated at 60fps with a CADisplayLink.

Version one wasn't meant to be optimized, but it appears to run very well.  CADisplayLink is fast and consistent.  However, when I looked at the allocation statistics...  Well, I've never seen anything like it.  ARC does a great job at keeping the Live Bytes under 1 megabyte, but this thing is shredding through 6 gigs a minute of overall allocations.

So my questions are:

Is this code dangerous to run on a device for long periods of time?  How "bad" is this?  Will apple even accept this or am I going to fry iPads if I continue developing like this?

[image]

Comment: It'll probably drain the battery of any device which tries to use the app very rapidly if anything which could be cause for concern with Apple.

Comment: The allocations instrument is not so great. Take a look at the VM Tracker one.

Comment: The allocations instrument is fantastic.   The VM tracker one is only useful if you are mapping/unmapping a lot of data.    Since most of the map/unmap events will be tied to an allocation, you are best off focusing on allocation rates anyway.

Comment: I didn't even think about battery drain!  But after checking the energy diagnostics, the power level is minimal (1/20).  I'm more worried about frying RAM chips, but I have no proof that it will happen.

I also used Allocations to look at Tremulous, a 3D game based off the Quake engine.  It averages about 50MB per minute of allocations, and it's a freakin 3D game, it seems like it should be crunching way more data than my little physics game.

I did check VM, 200mb virtual with 10mb Dirty and 45mb Res.  Those numbers are reasonable at least.  It doesn't seem like anyone's too concerned though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Optimizing to minimize allocation throughput is an exceptionally effective method to employ.

Notably, every allocation is likely going to require most of the bytes in the allocation to be touched, potentially a few writes and many reads, per every byte in the allocation.   All those reads/writes requires CPU cycles and transactions across the system bus.

So, yes, it will eat battery and will increase system temperature.   It is unlikely, though, to burn up the device. :)

Sort by the "#Transitory" and start figuring out how to eliminate transitory allocations.   I typically initially ignore the various Malloc ## Bytes allocations as those are most often backing stores in instances of some class.  Eliminate the transitory instance(s) and the # of mallocs drops, too.

For any given allocation type, you can click through to see a list of where all the allocations of that type were created.   Sort by the function name and then get a feel for the most common function.  Target your optimizations there.

Using this method, I've been able to massively optimize some large applications;  sometimes reducing the time of execution of certain operations by upwards of 75% by simply minimizing allocation rates!

Comment: Thank you for the extremely clear and helpful answer.  I looked at # Transitory and right up there under all the mallocs, climbing its way to the top of the list, is my Vector Object class.  I am literally allocating hundreds of Vectors per second, and then just throwing them away.  Turns out not to be a fatal design flaw, though.  Fixing ASAP!

Comment: Yeah, I've eliminated only a few unnecessary allocations, but it's already cut the memory usage down by 60%.  And it runs on a 3GS!  Super cool.  :)

Comment: @user892990 if you feel that bbum's answer was the 'correct' one, don't forget to flag it as such, so that he gets credit. :)